# Average of a variable over different levels of another variable in R

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset with employers, employees and salaries.
Each employee has a salary and is linked to an employer.
Employers can have hundreds, even thousands of employees working for them.
I want to find the average salary per employer. ie, I want to return an output with just 1 line per employer with an average salary based on all the employees they have.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example . Maybe you should have also a look at `?aggregate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` for this:

```
aggregate(salaries, by = list(employers), FUN = mean)
```

Comment: Thanks - this works! as you can tell, I'm new to R and also these forums. apologises if I don't know the rules...